# Getting a function to return rather than print

Tags: python, python-2.7, return

so I've managed to create a program that can be used to create a chessboard with configurable rows and columns:

```
def print_column_labels():
print "   a b c d e f g h"

def print_separator_row(num_columns):
print "   " +"+-" * num_columns+"+"

def print_squares_white(row_number, num_columns):
    if row_number<=9:
         print " "+str(row_number) +" "+"| |#" * (num_columns / 2)+"| "+str(row_number)
    else:
        print " "+ str(row_number ) +""+"|#| " * (num_columns / 2)+"| "+str(row_number)

def print_squares_black(row_number, num_columns):
    if row_number<=9:
       print " "+ str(row_number ) +" "+"|#| " * (num_columns / 2)+"| "+str(row_number)
    else:
        print " "+ str(row_number ) +""+"|#| " * (num_columns / 2)+"| "+str(row_number)

def print_chessboard(row_num,num_columns):
            print_column_labels()
            print_separator_row(num_columns)
            if row_num%2==0:
                    while row_num>=1:
                            print_squares_white(row_num,num_columns)
                            row_num-=1
                            print_separator_row(num_columns)
                            print_squares_black(row_num,num_columns)
                            row_num-=1
                            print_separator_row(num_columns)
                            if row_num==0:
                                    print_column_labels()
            else:
                    while row_num>=2:
                            print_squares_white(row_num,num_columns)
                            row_num-=1
                            print_separator_row(num_columns)
                            print_squares_black(row_num,num_columns)
                            row_num-=1
                            print_separator_row(num_columns)
                            if row_num==1:
                                    print_squares_white(row_num,num_columns)
                                    print_separator_row(num_columns)
                                    print_column_labels()
```

The next thing that I need to be able to do with the program is to change it from just printing the board to returning it as a string. How do I go about changing the code?

Comment: instead of `print`, use `return`

Comment: I tried replacing everywhere I use `print` with `return`, but I'm getting an ouput of `none`

Comment: How are you using the functions to get an output of `None`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def print_column_labels():
    return "   a b c d e f g h" + "\n"

def print_separator_row(num_columns):
    return "   " +"+-" * num_columns+"+" + "\n"

def print_squares_white(row_number, num_columns):
    if row_number<=9:
        return " "+str(row_number) +" "+"| |#" * (num_columns / 2)+"| "+str(row_number) + "\n"
    else:
        return " "+ str(row_number ) +""+"|#| " * (num_columns / 2)+"| "+str(row_number) + "\n"

def print_squares_black(row_number, num_columns):
    if row_number<=9:
        return " "+ str(row_number ) +" "+"|#| " * (num_columns / 2)+"| "+str(row_number) + "\n"
    else:
        return " "+ str(row_number ) +""+"|#| " * (num_columns / 2)+"| "+str(row_number) + "\n"

def print_chessboard(row_num,num_columns):
    result = ""
    result = result + print_column_labels()
    result = result + print_separator_row(num_columns)
    if row_num%2==0:
        while row_num>=1:
            result = result + print_squares_white(row_num,num_columns)
            row_num-=1
            result = result + print_separator_row(num_columns)
            result = result + print_squares_black(row_num,num_columns)
            row_num-=1
            result = result + print_separator_row(num_columns)
            if row_num==0:
                result = result + print_column_labels()
    else:
        while row_num>=2:
            result = result + print_squares_white(row_num,num_columns)
            row_num-=1
            result = result + print_separator_row(num_columns)
            result = result + print_squares_black(row_num,num_columns)
            row_num-=1
            result = result + print_separator_row(num_columns)
            if row_num==1:
                result = result + print_squares_white(row_num,num_columns)
                result = result + print_separator_row(num_columns)
                result = result + print_column_labels()

    return result

chessboard = print_chessboard(8,8)

print chessboard
```

Answer (score 2):

To return from a function, use `return`:

```
def myFunc(x):
    return x+2

var = myFunc(2)
print var # prints 4
```

---

This is what would happen if you used `print` instead:

```
def myFunc(x):
    print x+2

var = myFunc(2) # prints 4
print var # prints None
```

This is because if `return` is not called in a python function, python automatically assumes you wanted `return None` at the end of the function.  Not sure if this information helps, but it's there in case it does.

Answer (score 0):

You want to build your strings inside your functions and then return them at the end.

```
def get_column_labels():
    return "   a b c d e f g h"

def get_chessboard(row_num, num_columns):
    # start with an empty list
    rows = []
    # append the result of other functions to the list
    rows.append(get_column_labels()) 

    # ...

    # build the rows into a string and return it
    return '\n'.join(rows)
```